# Trying to prepend using ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to prepend text to an existing file.. This code works just great, BUT the last line never seems to execute. I can delete the original file, but the file is never renamed from the new temp file back to the original filename...

I'm sure it's something easy, but, I don't know why it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
# grab input text
s = "{query}"

# create insert value in template with timestamp
tmp = "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')}\n#{s}"

# path to file you wish to append...
# folder path must exist, file will be created if it doesn't
o = File.expand_path("~/Dropbox/Notes/1scratchpad.txt")
n = File.expand_path("~/Dropbox/Notes/1scratchpad.new.txt")

# open file in append mode and add the string
File.open(n, 'w') do |n|
    n.puts tmp
    n.puts "\n"
    File.foreach(o) do |li|
        n.puts li
    end
end

File.delete(o)
File.rename(n, o)
```

Comment: Could you please try `p File.delete(o)` and show us the output.

Comment: This is working for me as written. Ruby 1.9.3-p392, Mac OS X Server 10.5.8 PPC

Comment: Append mode is `a` FYI.

Comment: Have you tried in another directory instead of dropbox and maybe a simpler filename like *_new.txt instead of *.new.txt? Also I don't see a File.close(n).

Comment: I'm starting to think that it is because of dropbox to be honest.. It's actually supposed to be use as an Alfred.app workflow.. Works great, if not for the whole rename thing at the end ;)

Comment: This is working for me also, Ruby 1.9.3p329, Ubuntu x86.

Comment: @HM1 the `close` is not needed when you pass a block to `open`. The file is [automatically closed after the execution of the block](http://apidock.com/ruby/File/open/class).

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Maybe dropbox want to upload this file, and lock it? Try in other directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# grab input text
s = "{query}"

# create insert value in template with timestamp
tmp = "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')}\n#{s}"

# path to file you wish to append...
# folder path must exist, file will be created if it doesn't
o = File.expand_path("~/Dropbox/Notes/1scratchpad.txt")
n = File.expand_path("~/Dropbox/Notes/1scratchpad.new.txt")

# open file in append mode and add the string
File.open(n, 'a') do |n|
    n <<  tmp
    n << "\n"
    n << File.read(o)
end


#File.delete(o)
## Delete is no longer rename would take care of everthing
File.rename(n, o)
```